# Calling WCF service from Silverlight application ... problem

Tags: silverlight

I writing my first silverlight application. 
I calling some WCF service ( web service ) - the WCF service need to return simple string ( "hello word" ) - but i see that the only method that i can call are async. method - even if the method that the WCF service exposed are define as not async. method.

The WCF service work fine on simple winform client application.

What i did wrong ? 
why i getting this async method now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't done anything wrong. Web service calls in Silverlight are always async.
You can use the WaitHandle in the AsyncResult to deal with the request in a synchronous way, but make sure you do so on a background thread. Trying this on the main thread will block your application completely. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SynchronousSilverlight.aspx) for more explanation.

If you dislike writing async code in the traditional way (like me), you could try downloading the [Visual Studio async CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360), which allows for a much cleaner syntax for dealing with asynchronous code.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the Visual studio async CTP only supports Silverlight 5, which may or may not be an issue.